# statistics and biased estimator of normal distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ be independent, identically distributed random variables from a population with mean $\mu =10$ and variance $\sigma ^2=10$. Let$$\overline Y=\frac{X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4}{4}$$denote the average of these four random variables (in other words, the sample mean).

a) What is the expected value and variance of $\overline Y$?

b) Now, consider a different estimator of $\mu$:$$\displaystyle W=\frac{X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4}{8}.$$This is an example of a weighted average of the $X_i$.  What is the expected value and  variance of $W$?

c) Based on your answers on parts (a) and (b), which estimator of $\mu$ do you prefer, $\overline Y$ or $W$?

Attempt:

a) I got $\mathbb{E}(X)=10$, but variance known formula is $\mathbb{E}(X^2)-\mathbb{E}(X)^2$ but got stuck there.

b) $\dfrac{20}{8}+\dfrac{10}{4}+5=\text{mean}$, and stuck on variance.

c) Checking unbiasness?

Comment: Please check your definition of $W.$ Aren't a couple of the coefficients 3/8 instead of 1/8? Meanwhile, All parts but (a) depend on getting that right. In (a), $V(\bar X) = V(X_i)/4 = 10/4.$ Your book must have a formula such as $V(aX + bY) = a^2V(X) + b^2V(Y)$ for independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. Do you see the connection? I'll check in the morning to see your response, and to see if someone has given further help by then.

Comment: I see that @iadvd has kindly tried to put your question into better mathematical form, but botched $\bar Y = (X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4)/4.$ Your original notation was not the best, but I guess the intent obvious to any statistician.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo thanks for finding that, I forgot that one!

Comment: @Did: The variance formula quoted should be $V(X) = E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2,$ but per my earlier comment it is not actually what is needed in part (a).

Comment: @BruceTrumbo OK. Why are you telling me this?

Comment: @Did: Sorry, I thought the error in typography had to do with your edit.

Answer (score 2):

a) Your answer for expected value is correct. To find the variance you need to use the formulae:

- $\operatorname{Var}(aX)=a^2\operatorname{Var}(X)$ for any real number $a$ and random variable X
- $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y) = \operatorname{Var}(X) +\operatorname{Var}(Y)$ for independent random variables $X$ and $Y$

Therefore,
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{1}{4}\left(X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4 \right) \right) &= \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 \operatorname{Var}\left(X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4\right) \\
 &= \frac{1}{16} \left(\operatorname{Var}(X_1) + \operatorname{Var}(X_2) + \operatorname{Var}(X_3) + \operatorname{Var}(X_4) \right) \\
 &= \frac{1}{16} (10 + 10 + 10 + 10) \\
 &= 2.5
\end{align}

b) Following the method from part a) should give you an answer to this. I'll leave it to you as you will understand it better if you try it yourself!

c) An estimator is unbiased if its expectation is equal to the true mean (in this case, 10). Unbiasedness is generally a good thing. Another thing to consider is the variance of an estimator, which you want to be small (you don't want your estimator to change each time you resample). If both estimators are unbiased, then the better estimator is the one with smaller variance.